# spark standalone cluster - privilege issue in creating output file

Tags: apache-spark, privileges, nfs

I'm working with spark standalone cluster (Linux platform and python application), using nfs to share files across master and worker machines. I'm trying with a master and one worker machine and able to submit application, it runs in worker machine but it fails to create output file (using spark saveAsTextFile), throws mkdir failed error. In both master and worker machine the nfs directory have the permission to create and delete files and I'm able to create it manually but when spark tries to create files inside that directory it creates the temporary folders ( _temporary and 0 folders) but fails to create part files. 
I have tried using "chmod -R 777", but still it fails. Is there any way to make it work!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a privilege issue.
When you Create a directory in NFS you have to provide directory privilege using

**chown username:groupname path-of-the-NFS-directory**

Then you must run spark application using privileged user or group.

If you still facing that issue 
you could try these

**chgrp group name path-of-the-NFS-directory**

And then try,

**chmod 777 path-of-the-NFS-directory**

This will work.

Comment: yep, you are correct, I tried this and it works.. but for performance issue, I moved to hdfs instead of nfs